# What is the best way to deal with people asking many zero-voted questions?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, voting, zero-voted-posts

My example is someone who posted about 250 questions and 40 answers, but most of the questions are pretty simple and not very highly voted. Indeed about 60 questions have positive scores, about 30 questions have negative scores and the overwhelming rest (~160) have zero score. 30 out of 40 answers have zero score. The total rep is about 900 which is not much given the number of questions and answers.

It is quite clear that this user prefers asking on SO over working through manuals/books/... and indeed when you take all questions together you would get something like a beginners tutorial but from a highly fragmented and specific perspective.

My impression is that SO is the primary learning ressource in this case. The effect on SO will be many more low quality questions (low quality approximated here by zero score).

So I wonder, should I downvote these questions more often or would this be too harsh and such questions have a place on SO too?

Furthermore: Should the sheer number of similarly low quality questions play a role when evaluating the quality of a single question or should still each question be regarded completely independent from any history of the questioner?

Comment: Downvoting a lot of questions of one particular user ... yeah. But then the system works *against* you: (1) you will be marked a "stalker" and "serial downvoter", and (2) all of your downvotes will be retracted.

Comment: @Jongware Is this really happening when you do it only whenever the questions are published? Like when you happen to see that last 10 questions of someone published on different days and you happen to downvote them, will the system judge you as a "serial downvoter"?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions

Comment: How many of these questions would be duplicates? If none, tthey could even be helping the site, providing a resoure for others searhing for the same info (and not realizing they should upvote). If there are duplicates, then things could use a clean-up and that would be a better investment of your time?

Comment: @CindyMeister Not sure how many are duplicates. A thorough scrutiny may reveal that a considerable part are duplicated, the others may be very specialized or presented in a convoluted, not very clear way. I would probably not consider improving them or searching for duplicates a good investment of my time.

Comment: Look at all the resent questions from the person, and use your power to close them if they justify being closed.   And provided the reviewers in the close queue agree, the person will soon get a question ban.

Comment: @IanRingrose Targetting persons specifically (for example checking all their questions) is not recommended. See for example the recent discussion [Chain upvoting / downvoting / flagging posts of a user? (Not revenge / grace voting.)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400433/chain-upvoting-downvoting-flagging-posts-of-a-user-not-revenge-grace-vot)..

Comment: @Trilarion the difference with closing (unlike down voting) is that the question then gets review by other people.

Answer (score 16):

Concentrate on the **post** rather than the **poster**.

When you come across a question evaluate it on it's own merits and down-vote, flag/vote to close, comment and/or answer as you see fit. If there is someone posting questions in the tags you frequent and you are consistently down-voting their questions then **as long as you are doing this as part of your normal activity** then there shouldn't be any issue. It's only if you start going through someone's questions systematically that the serial voting scripts kick in.

If you down-vote or vote/flag to close a lot of their questions then they might start to see warning messages etc. telling them that their questions aren't being well received. Automatic flags are raised if someone has multiple questions closed in a short period of time and we can send a message when we process that.

However, someone with 250 questions is unlikely to get affected by the automatic question block, so the simple answer might be just to ignore these questions and find something more interesting to answer. If enough people did this then this sort of question would be asked less frequently as people would learn than to get an answer on Stack Overflow you need to ask a **good, well researched** question.

Comment: That's a lot of good advice. I read from that that mostly everything should stay as it is. You actually can use SO as primary learning ressource as long as this only means getting zero-voted questions (not negatively ones).

Comment: @Trilarion - if your goal is to get answers rather than build rep (which to be honest it *should* be if you're asking questions) then SO works wonderfully for you.

Comment: "If enough people did this then this sort of question would be asked less frequently", but as there are always enough users who answer any question, no matter how inane, unresearched or unclear (never hurts to guess what OP wants, right?), people will probably never learn that you need to ask good, well researched questions on SO...

Comment: @l4mpi Unfortunately that is true. I added that more in hope than expectation ;)