# Chain upvoting / downvoting / flagging posts of a user? (Not revenge / grace voting.)

Tags: discussion, flags, downvotes, voting, upvotes

[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398050/8565438) to the question: [Is it okay to look for good posts to upvote after downvoting a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398049/is-it-okay-to-look-for-good-posts-to-upvote-after-downvoting-a-post) states that:

> Votes should be on content, not on users. Do not go to the user's profile page to look for stuff to vote on, whether up or down.

However, **users behind good / bad / duplicate posts** (in my experience) **tend to write other posts which are good / bad / duplicate**.

If I see such a post *on a topic which I am familiar with*, & it very much deserves an upvote / downvote / flag in my assessment, **why shouldn't I check out the other posts of that user, & see if other posts deserve one of my actions?** I am *not going for expressing gratitude / punishing a user*, I am going for *posts which I can judge*. (And users who post on a topic which I can judge tend to have more posts on that topic.)

After all, votes (& flags) are making the site better. There are many discussions on meta, which result in the conclusion that voting is paramount & should not be restricted (ie by making downvote explanations mandatory, etc).

Comment: Because at that point, you are biased. You are deciding to look at that person's posts, *because you think other posts of theirs may be X*

Comment: A lot of SO users actually do this.  It is generally only perceived as a problem when they do it to downvote posts.  If you do it to upvote, and don't take the time to actually read and learn from the posts, then such votes are likely to be detected as fraudulent and rolled-back.

Comment: This has been discussed quite a lot on Meta SE. One such question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138517/how-to-vote-on-friends-colleagues-questions-or-answers

Comment: What's stopping you from upvoting a post which should be marked as dupe? Regardless of user are you going to evaluate each post with unbiased merit?

Comment: Sometimes I do vote up duplicates (in accordance with the answer to this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265843/8565438). Yeah, probably it's true that I am biased when voting on multiple posts of a single.user.

Comment: Many times when interacting with a user (Question, Answer, Comments) and I see that they have good knowledge of a topic, I'll often take a peek at their other answers. The goal is for me to learn from them, not to vote on them.   Occasionally I do find something useful in this somewhat less-random-than-a-tag-with-thousands-of-questions browsing, and vote on it.  I tend to avoid doing that more than once or twice, however, to avoid the "appearance" of anything nefarious.

Comment: What helps is to always read the other answers on questions that the targeted user has answered, to give you something to compare to.

Comment: See also [my question here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348135/should-we-refrain-completely-from-close-voting-by-user), which focusses on serial close-voting.

Comment: i never did this. i had some conflicts with users up to this point, but for me this was always a random name in a post, and after the thread is closed, i'd never hold a grudge against said user afterwards

Comment: @KevinB Sometimes the person's posts are so obviously X, that even if you were to reverse your bias (actively look for reasons the post is not X, and try to ignore evidence of X) you still cannot escape the conclusion.

Comment: @kev To me that statement reads like it's echoing SO's (un)official mantra: *"We trust our users! Well, somewhat. Sometimes anyway. Oh, scrap that! No, we do not trust our users just enough to give them unlimited tools."* By calling it *"bias"*, though, you have preemptively demoted our abilities to recognize patterns. It's almost as if suggesting that opening a user's profile page will inevitably lead to poor decisions. That's not something I can get behind.

Comment: I find that the most convincing argument is that it is not distinguishable from revenge voting by the system easily, so the gain by allowing users to have this freedom is less than the damage done by those users who don't use this freedom well & revenge vote.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> why shouldn't I check out the other posts of that user, & see if other posts deserve one of my actions?

Because you are biased and targeting someone personally.

- For actions that are *not* peer reviewed and with *no* recourse, this is **bad**. Votes for example. The person has no way to appeal a downvote and others are not notified to correct your action if you are wrong.
- For actions that are *peer reviewed* and can be *appealed*, this is **good**. If you see spam, by all means check the user's other recent posts and flag them too if they are spam. If they have a history of posting duplicates, check the duplicate and close vote them. You see an insulting comment, please flag all of them, not just one.

Comment: What if you're browsing a user's history and realize that user is solely answering questions caused by typos?

Comment: I guess you could close-vote the questions. Other than that... what would you do? I wouldn't do anything at all. If it's a solid answer to a good question, why bother? I'm happy if someone takes the time to point out my stupid typo mistakes.

Comment: I don't find that a good answer, since questions caused by typos are meant to be closed, _specifically_ so users won't post an answer. Pointing out a typo is hardly _"a solid answer to a good question"_.

Comment: Sorry, I beg to differ. Yes, the question should be closed, but only people *spotting* the typo should close it and and least *one* of them should answer and explain what the typo is. Closing a question because of a typo *and not explaining where it is* is something I would describe as a Richard's change of location over time.

Comment: Whenever I close vote typos, I write a short comment that points out the typo but it's usually not worth an answer.

Comment: While helpful, comments aren't meant to last forever and have limited space. I do that too, if it's a really stupid, obvious typo that really needs no explanation. But I don't think we need to punish people for "helping wrong". If they want to write an answer and it actually answer the question... then I'm happy to just leave them be.

Comment: *comments aren't meant to last forever* -  and questions closed as typo should also not last forever, that's why we close them. And if you're running out of space explaining a typo in a comment, you should reconsider if this is really a typo.

Comment: Answering typo questions directly goes against getting them removed from the site. It's literally a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: Well, you are free to use your downvotes as you like, so am I. I cannot keep you from downvoting it if you think it has to be downvoted. But in this case it does not matter whether it's deserved or not. if it happens while specifically crawling a single user's answer's, it's targeted and the script will hopefully remove it, while close-voting the question, something that is peer reviewed and can be corrected by other users if done in error, -in my opinion- is perfectly fine.

Comment: Down-votes are somewhat subjective in the sense that I'm free to down-vote whatever I want. Thus I can't really be "wrong" when I down-vote. It's my vote to do what I want. I'm certainly not advocating serial down-voting here, which is a form of targeting and harassment. But down-voting because I legitimately don't think a question or answer is useful is fine. That's what they're for. They can't and *shouldn't be able to* be corrected by peers.

Comment: If someone writes an answer to a question that should be closed as a typo I wouldn't bother downvoting it, but I might post a brief comment explaining why it's not desirable to write such answers. Closed typo questions are normally automatically deleted after several days, but upvoted or accepted answers block that process. So 3 people with delete privileges (or a mod) need to delete it manually. Consequently, the site gets littered with undeleted typo questions that are very unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: You're not targeting anyone personally. You're targeting an account; that is not a person. It could be three people. It could be someone's AI experiment. Or even a really clever dog! On the Internet, nobody knows you're really a dog.

Comment: How can you know that he is biased? Why do you assume that everyone is evil? Your whole answer sounds like a cognitive bias.

Comment: The point OP makes is that his bias is justified. *users behind good / bad / duplicate posts (in my experience) tend to write other posts which are good / bad / duplicate.*

Comment: Saying that reviewing a user's post history is bias implies that a user's behavior isn't biased. Many users are "biased" towards a bad use of this site. Like it or not, 90% of answers/comments are simply ignored on this site. Very rarely will people upvote/downvote, even if a question deserves it. IMO, it's reasonable to review a user's history to check if they have a bias towards misuse of this site. For the same reason that 3 incorrect audits will get you a review ban.

Answer (score 25):

You can find topics you're familiar with via tags. Use that to find questions to vote on.

- What we find otherwise is that someone gets annoyed with someone else and downvotes many of their answers.
- Equally someone wants to reward a good answer and rather than doing it via the bounty system which costs them rep, they sidestep that and upvote many answers.

Both of these things are problematic and the system reverses such voting. How is the system supposed to know you're

> not going for a expressing gratitude / punishing a user, I am going for posts which I can judge

Avoid doing something that may be misinterpreted. You might know you're not a sockpuppet of the person you're upvoting but if your actions indicate otherwise then you'll suffer the consequences i.e. possible account deletion.

Comment: Does this hold for flagging for duplicates as well?

Comment: @zabop voting to close as duplicate is public action- I don’t see how voting to close dozen of user’s questions in short time would not look like targeting. Till you get to 3k you can only flag for duplicate which is far less public (maybe info is available in SEDE not sure) - so enjoy anonymity for now. Also just random fact that many questions are voted on is rare and hence would be suspicious, likely causing meta discussion... Basically - just don’t target users

Comment: This is more on target than the accepted answer. SE telling me what is a bad attitude goes beyond their legitimate concern. "This person has some great posts and deserves more credit" isn't to me obnoxious. The key is indeed that posts should be up- or down-voted on merit. Nevertheless, that attitude is nowhere near as obnoxious as "This person annoyed the heck out of me and so I am downvoting their stuff". But given that attitudes are private, unless explained in a comment, it is in practice fair that the software will reverse downvoting/upvoting sprees as _likely_ to be misguided.

Answer (score 8):

> If I see such a post on a topic which I am familiar with & it very much deserves an upvote / downvote / flag in my assessment, Why shouldn't I check out the other posts of that user, & see if other posts deserve one of my actions?

Well, you should be able to do that. It is your own decision and right to look at whatever you want to on the site (no one can and should prevent you from doing that), but be careful:

Just because you downvoted or flagged a post of one user doesn't mean you should or need to equalize your doing, because you have a feeling of guilt.

This feeling of guilt shouldn't taint your ability to judge on posts impartial, which is likely to be the case when trying to get off your guilt feelings.

The same goes for the opposite case. Just because you think a user has many questions and/or answers which are upvoted pretty well (and maybe in your opinion "*not in an appropriate manner*"), doesn't mean you should equalize by downvote or flag this or other posts of the same author.

Doing so is absolutely inappropriate.

You need to stay focused and always judge upon whether the post is *really* good or not and not based upon whether the author (or you with your feelings) needs equalization.

This is also what the first sentence of the quote you gave "*Votes should be on content, not on users*" correctly described and I fully agree with. "*users*" also do not only describe the author of the post, it is also you, who judge.

Comment: The opposit case is true, too. If you like somebody and "stalk" his good posts, you will tend to upvote him and downvote other answeres. There is no problem with beeing a fan of another coder (or user in general), but it's a bias after all. If you want to show some respect to another user, maybe tag them in a question you think would fit them, otherwise it's a good practise to look at each question like it was a new thread regardless of who asked and answered it.

Comment: @clockw0rk I already was at the draft yesterday to add it but I rejected it because of no time. Thank you to hinting me again.

Comment: As I read the question, its author doesn't want to *"equalize"* votes, or get some sort of *"guilt feelings"* off of their shoulders. They are asking about an efficient way to rate a whole slew of contributions. Which the system prevents them from doing, by exercising a biased judgement on certain voting patterns. *"What, 3 votes on contributions from the same author by a user? That cannot possibly be benevolent!"*.

Comment: @IInspectable Good point. I missed that part of the question. I want to cover it in a full edit.

Answer (score 7):

> why shouldn't I check out the other posts of that user, & see if other posts deserve one of my actions?

Nothing is stopping you; I've done the same in the past, mostly to see whether the scenario I'm viewing is a once-off or a pattern.

If the former, I'll go no further; for the latter I'll mod-flag the question that started my exploration with a note to that effect, and let the higher powers handle as they see fit.

At the end of the day, it really isn't worth your time and effort to concentrate on a single user, when there are so many pouring unmitigated crap into the site. Especially considering that your activity is likely to be detected as revenge downvoting and automatically reversed, which means the time and effort you spent is effectively wasted.

Answer (score 3):

I hold [one question which the community considers bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233124/addition-method-to-java-class). At the time, I had copied over Kotlin code, rewrote a bit to change the question to Java, and forgot to rewrite the bottom bit. Also, I didn't want to write a method, what I really wanted was operator overloading, and I didn't know the term for that.

It got -10 within 5 minutes, which was fair. However, even when the question was fixed, it continued to get several more downvotes. And there would be downvotes on other random questions/answers I've posted in the past.

I think a lot of people came in with the mindset of policing, so they read the question in the most negative possible interpretation, and then went on and search for negative interpretations of my past questions, based on that question.

One example is in the answer there, where someone posted `// alternatively throw an exception or error` and someone else decided to interpret that as an Error subclass, then edited out the "error" word without giving a proper suggestion. It could have been improved, but instead, everyone just smelled blood, attacked, then left.